# List a Status even when there are no records in the resultset with that status when querying with t-sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am creating a summary report with columns Status, Count, and Amount.  How do I list a status even if no records in the query result match that status?  Sample data offered in below image:

[image]

When I query for the report (counting those records in the table that match the Status), I get the following results:

[image]

How can I get the result to match the first table, which includes Status C (there are no records with a status of C)?

Comment: What does your query look like currently?

Comment: The current query: 'select 
 case when status = '52' then 'Submitted' else '' end as 'Status'
, COUNT(billno) as [Count]
, SUM(amtpaid) as [Amount Paid]
from BillTBL
where Client = 1491 and 
status = '52''

Comment: Thanks @marc_s. I didn't realize it wouldn't format the way it did in the original post.  I appreciate your guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a left join. You have not included your schema but an example would be:

```
SELECT S.Name AS Status, COALESCE(COUNT(T.*),0) AS [Count], 
    COALESCE(SUM(T.Amount),0) AS Amount
FROM Status S
LEFT OUTER JOIN myTable T ON S.Id = T.StatusId
GROUP BY S.ID, S.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select Status, Count(*) Count, Sum(Amount) Amount
From Table1 
Left Outer Join Table2 ON table1.Status = Table2.Status
Group By Table1.Status
```